# Increment Time by one second in a loop

Tags: java, datetime, time

Here is a simple test: I am trying to increment current timestamp by 1 second in a loop. The output is not what I expect.

```
public class TimeTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, i);
            System.out.println("Updated  = " + cal.getTime());
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of neat 1 second increments, I get increments from anywhere between 5 seconds to 1 second.

```
Updated  = Mon May 13 15:12:45 PDT 2013
Updated  = Mon May 13 15:12:46 PDT 2013
Updated  = Mon May 13 15:12:48 PDT 2013
Updated  = Mon May 13 15:12:51 PDT 2013
Updated  = Mon May 13 15:12:55 PDT 2013
Updated  = Mon May 13 15:13:00 PDT 2013
Updated  = Mon May 13 15:13:06 PDT 2013
Updated  = Mon May 13 15:13:13 PDT 2013
Updated  = Mon May 13 15:13:21 PDT 2013
Updated  = Mon May 13 15:13:30 PDT 2013
```

Comment: Hint: the increments are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9 (in that order!) :)

Comment: FDinoff is right. The first time you add 1 second, then 2 seconds, then 3 seconds, then +x seconds... :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to add `1` instead of `i` on each for loop iteration.

```
cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
```

Simply increment the calendar by 1 second instead of *i seconds*